# LogStash - DNS Filter Nameserver from file

Tags: dns, logstash

Im using DNS filter in a LogStash's pipeline.
From official DOC nameserver has to be an array:

```
dns {
   nameserver => {
                   address => [ "8.8.8.8",  "8.8.4.4" ]
                 }
```

If not set, logstash will use /etc/resolv.conf

I need to read the nameserver addresses from file because they can be changed from my Frontend Application.
Im generating a dns.yml file but I don't know how to force dns filter to use my dictionary.

Is it possible?

Comment: It is not possible, you need to set it in the filter or in `resolv.conf`. But it is not clear what your issue is, you mean that depending on your frontend application the nameserver used is different? If so you can use conditionals and multiple dns filters. Can you give an example of what you are trying to do and update your question?

Comment: On frontend, an user can set a list of CIDR consideret, by logstash, as "internal". Then the user can configure a list of Internal DNS and External DNS so when logstash check an IP can switch from internal DNS (usually for internal IPs) and external (google for example).
On resolv.conf you put every DNS regardless of ip